# How to send a get form wthout losing get parameters

Tags: php, forms, get, opencart

I have a form located at a url containing get parameters,my form is also using this method.When the form is submitted it rewrites the previos get parameters.
Is there a simple way to rewrite only my form parameters?

I have in mind a Javascript solution ,however I want to know if there is a simpler way?Using HTML/PHP perhaps?

Comment: Send form to the url containing old get parameters. Page A: pageA?old=param contains form should sent form to Page B: pageB?old=param and not to pageB. And add your code to see how far are you now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lets say you get a parameter p1 from a get request, it should look like this:

```
http://server.com/?p1=123
```

In your form, you can add hidden fields that would have the same effect when you submit, like this:

```
<form method="GET">
<input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $_GET["p1"]; ?>" name="p1">
</form>
```

That way you can resend the variables as many times as you need.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know, u u are not interested in using JS, then using form's hidden element is only way u have like this-

```html
<form action="demo_form.asp">
  First name: <input type="text" name="fname"><br>
  <input type="hidden" name="country" value="Norway">
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>

<p>Notice that the hidden field above is not shown to a user.</p>
```

The question is how u can use it with PHP, right?

The solution is here-

```
//In PHP
if( isset($_GET['fromPerson']) )
{
     echo $fromPerson;
}
```

So combined HTML and PHP code will be like this (assuming a get element from prevous page is named **fromPerson**)-

```php
<form action="demo_form.asp">
      First name: <input type="text" name="fname"><br>

      <?php
         if( isset($_GET['fromPerson']) )
         {
            echo '<input type="hidden" name="country" value=".$_POST['fromPerson'].">';
         }

      ?>

      <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I understand your question... Can you post your code?

I assume you mean something like this?
in index.php

```
<input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo $id; ?>" />
```

in return.php

```
<a href="index.php?id=' . $user['id'] . '">Edit</a>
```